# Не хочет работать HDD WD

Tags: hdd, bios, диск

Купил [HDD WD](https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/624b90183ebf3330/10-tb-zestkij-disk-wd-purple-wd100purz/) на 10tb для бэкапов, и думал что он как обычно зайдет по сата, но не тут то было. Он не хочет работать у меня на компе, проверял его у других - он работает!

Comment: Без пояснений, что означает «не хочет работать», и соответствующих логов и текстов ошибок (при их наличии) помочь будет трудно

Comment: Основное решение - все таки подружить его с вашей машиной. Если напрямую ни как (что странно), попробовать подключить через переходник через USB. Если и это не поможет, то подключить диск к тому, где он работает и передавать данные по сети

Comment: даже в биосе не видит. Я пробовал подключать его через переходник SATA to usb. Слышно что блины крутятся, но по прежнему нету доступа. Есть подозрение что для него нужно менять материнку, но как бы это точно узнать какая подойдет к нему мать.

Comment: @andreymal какие логи или ошибки, он даже на аппаратном уровне не определяется. Даже в биосе не видит. Не говоря уже о системе.

Comment: @Mike, чтобы работал по usb, нужен специальный адаптер. Во-первых, у него должно быть самостоятельное питание - без него только 2.5 работают. Во-вторых, тот адаптер, который есть у меня, умеет работать только с дисками до 2 ТБ - c 3 ТБ уже не работает, а тут аж 10. Так что вероятность заставить работать через usb гораздо меньше, чем нормально через sata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась обновлением БИОСа, после чего диски стали отображаться как положено. Обновить БИОС посоветовали [тут](https://toster.ru/q/598833).